# .htaccess redirect from one subfolder to other subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know this sounds like so many other questions here, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Say you are on:
 www.domain.com/folderA/folder2/folder3/

I want that to redirect to:
 www.domain.com/folderB/folder2/folder3/

So the whole structure stays the same.. it just redirects.
Now so far I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folderA [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folderB/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when I use that, it'll just do
 www.domain.com/folderB/folderA/folder2/folder3/

What am I doing wrong? How do I get rid of that folderA?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The pattern `^(.*)$` includes also the prefix `folderA`. You must specify `folderA` explicitly in the pattern and capture only the latter part in the RewriteRule. Then you can drop the RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?folderA/(.*)$ /folderB/$1 [R,L]
```

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.