# .htaccess redirect add a subfolder to a link path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to add a subfolder into my path. Is it possible with htaccess?
My pattern looks like:
domainname/workgroups/page/[any given content]

It needs to redirect or rewrite to
domainname/category/workgroups/page/[any given conent]

I want to keep the url including whatever wildcard stuff comes after /page/, but I need to jam a /category/ in the url after the domain.

My question is similar to this:
[.htaccess redirect from one subfolder to other subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904793/htaccess-redirect-from-one-subfolder-to-other-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/workgroups/page(.*) domainname/category/workgroups/page$1
```

I don't know what that caret is for, but the redirect doesn't work without it.